# How do I use a simple test spy in a controller test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test that my controller simply calls a method on a service object.  I thought a test spy would be perfect for this.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for any help!

Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      ServiceObject.new(@post).call
      redirect_to posts_path, success: "#{@post.title} was successfully created."
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end

end
```

Service object:

```
class ServiceObject

  def initialize(post)
    @post = post
  end

  def call
    puts "Service object was called!"
  end

end
```

Controller test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PostsController do
  describe 'POST #create' do
    it 'calls the service object' do
      service_object = double(ServiceObject)
      service_object.stub(:new).and_return(service_object)
      service_object.stub(:call)
      post :create, post: Fabricate.attributes_for(:post)
      expect(service_object).to have_received(:call)
    end
  end
end
```

Error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(service_object).to have_received(:call)
  (Double ServiceObject).call(any args)
      expected: 1 time with any arguments
      received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Comment: have you checked that post is being saved and that ```if @post.save``` is returning true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PostsController do
  describe 'POST #create' do
    let(:service_object) { double(:service_object) }

    before do
      ServiceObject.stub(:new).and_return(service_object)
      service_object.stub(:call)
    end  

    it 'calls the service object' do
      post :create, post: Fabricate.attributes_for(:post)

      expect(service_object).to have_received(:call)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Well that worked!  The main difference I'm seeing is the way I created the double: "double(ServiceObject)" vs "double(:service_object)".  May need to go back and revisit doubles.  Thanks!

Comment: yes that's right - that's the key difference... that's creating a mock object identified by the key ```:service_object```... then we have to stub the ```ServiceObject``` class's ```new``` method to return that mock object on which we in turn stub ```call``` on and then build the expectation that it receives the message ```call```